# String match in the dependencies of pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I am trying to add a dependency to the latest "development release" of a python project to my `pyproject.toml`.

Here's what I am trying:

```
[project]
dependencies = [
  'some-package>=*.dev'
]
```

I can use the exact same string with `pip install` but for some reason it doesn't work (it complains about the string format not being compliant to pep508) in this context. Can someone help me?

EDIT 1:

Here's a toy example which is easy to reproduce.

1. In a `python:3.10` docker image, with the following `pyproject.toml` dependencies:

```
...
dependencies = [
  'numpy ~= "*.post"',
]
```

(`numpy` only used as an example. The same about the post released version)
2) Here's what I get:

```
root@4c2f2feb3dcc:/code# pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///code
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [48 lines of output]
      configuration error: `project.dependencies[0]` must be pep508
      DESCRIPTION:
          Project dependency specification according to PEP 508
      
      GIVEN VALUE:
          "numpy ~= \"*.post\""
      
      OFFENDING RULE: 'format'
      
      DEFINITION:
          {
              "$id": "#/definitions/dependency",
              "title": "Dependency",
              "type": "string",
              "format": "pep508"
          }
...
```

So, in short, I believe that I am having issues with basic string matching and hence it is very likely that I am doing it the wrong way.

At the same time, if one try to follow the grammar test provided in the [pep508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#complete-grammar), it seems to be compliant.

EDIT 2:

I did try to debug further. The error message I got is the following:

```
...

File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3uwr9l70/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py", line 51, in validate
      raise ValueError(f"{error}\n{summary}") from None

...
```

If one inspects this file, here's where the exception is raised: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/245d72a8aa4d47e1811425213aba2a06a0bb64fa/setuptools/config/_validate_pyproject/fastjsonschema_validations.py#L904

I didn't have time to debug further though. When trying to use the parsing script + grammar provided in PEP508 the dependency is parsed as

```
numpy ~= *.post -> ('numpy', [], [('~=', '*.post')], None)
```

So, definitely a tuple. And the version is correctly parsed as `*.post`.

Comment: Could you post the exact text of the error message?  I think the problem is related to having `>=*.dev'`, as `>=` would usually go with a numeric value comparison.  At the very least, `*.dev` would need to be quoted so you're using >= in a string comparison, so `"some-package >= '*.dev'"`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety, I added more info. Now it should be fully reproducible.

Comment: According to PEP 508, version numbers and version comparisions are defined in [PEP 440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/).  According to PEP 440, there need to be two  numeric segments before the '.post', so you would need `"*.*.post"` or `"*.*-post"` which would be normalized to the first format.  It would probably be better to specify a more specific version you want the post release of, however. 
  If that resolves the issue I can write up a more complete and detailed answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry it took so long. None of those worked. Moreover, in the end it was more like an investigative question since the better solution is to have a specific version. I did debug a little bit and the source of the error is in the parsing of the dependencies. I added another update with my findings.

Comment: Huh... I am quite confused by what you are trying to achieve... I think maybe you want to use [`python -m pip install --pre ...`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-pre). As far as I can remember `>=*.dev` and `~= "*.post"` are not valid version constraint specifiers. -- Anyway, I think you are attacking the problem from the wrong angle. It is not good practice to try to enforce "latest development release" at the project packaging metadata level. It should be up to the user doing the installation to decide if they want to use pre- or dev-releases or not.